# Is there a fast way to determine the conjugacy classes of $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I was working towards proving $A_5$ is the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_5$. To do this, I wanted to find a set of representatives of conjugacy classes of $S_5$, and their respective orders.

With some research, I found that $1, (12), (123), (12)(34), (1234), (12)(345), (12345)$ are a set of representatives, with orders $1,10,20,15,30,20,24$. What is the most efficient way to determine something like this by hand, without taking an element $\sigma$, conjugating it by all $120$ elements of $S_5$, and then doing it again with a new element which wasn't in the orbit of $\sigma$ until the set is exhausted?

Comment: Conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are just the cycle types.

Comment: [Conjugate Permutations have Same Cycle Type](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type) and [Cycle Decomposition of Conjugate](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_Decomposition_of_Conjugate) at ProofWiki.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the effect of conjugation on cycles. Given the cycle $c=(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_k)$ and $\sigma\in S_n$, the permutation $\sigma c\sigma^{-1}$ maps $\sigma(a_i)$ to $\sigma(a_{i+1})$ (cycle the index modulo $k$), and all other arguments are fixed by the permutation. Hence

$$c^\sigma=\sigma(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_k)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma (a_1)~\sigma(a_2)~\cdots~\sigma(a_k)).$$

If $c_1,\cdots,c_l$ are disjoint cycles, $\sigma(c_1\cdots c_l)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma c_1\sigma^{-1})\cdots(\sigma c_l\sigma^{-1})$, hence conjugation preserves not only cycles and cycle lengths, but cycle types as well. Moreover, conjugation acts transitively on permutations of a given cycle type. Suppose $\pi=c_1\cdots c_l$ and $\rho=d_1\cdots d_l$ are two permutations and their disjoint cycle decompositions such that each $c_i$ and $d_i$ have the same length.

We construct a $\sigma$ in pieces: if $c_i=(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_k)$ and $d_i=(b_1~b_2~\cdots~b_k)$ (note $k$ can vary with $i$), let $\sigma$ send $a_j\mapsto b_j$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,k$. After doing this for each cycle (even the ones of length one, which are normally left out of written representations for efficiency), we will have that $\sigma \pi \sigma^{-1}=\rho$, by having equivalent cycle decompositions. This $\sigma$ is not unique; we could rewrite $c_i$ cycled by $1$ in index as $(a_k~a_1~\cdots~a_{k-1})$ and $\sigma$ would turn out different.

Cycle types are in bijection with [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). For $n=5$, we have

$$\begin{array}{c | c}\lambda\vdash5 & \sigma \\ \hline (5) & (1~2~3~4~5) \\
(4,1) & (1~2~3~4)(5) \\
(3,2) & (1~2~3)(4~5) \\
(3,1,1) & (1~2~3)(4)(5) \\
(2,2,1) & (1~2)(3~4)(5) \\
(2,1,1,1) & (1~2)(3)(4)(5) \\
(1,1,1,1,1) & (1)(2)(3)(4)(5) \end{array}$$

On the left are integer partitions of $5$, and on the right are easily constructed representatives (in cycle notation) of the conjugacy class - cycle type - associated to the partition.

Answer (score 2):

If $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are permutations, then $\sigma\pi\sigma^{-1}$ has the same cycle type as $\pi$.  To see why this is, suppose $\pi$ contains the cycle $(12345)$.  Then $\sigma\pi\sigma^{-1}$ takes $\sigma(1)$ to $1$, then to $2$ and then to $\sigma(2)$.  So the cycle $(12345)$ turns into the cycle $(\sigma(1)\; \sigma(2)\; \sigma(3)\; \sigma(4)\; \sigma(5) )$.

This means that the conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are exactly the sets of permutations which have the same cycle type when written in disjoint cycle notation.  In $A_n$, the problem is a little more complicated, as two permutations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ that have the same cycle type might not have an *even* permutation $\sigma$ such that $\pi_2=\sigma\pi_1\sigma^{-1}$.  It turns out that the conjugacy classes in $A_n$ are the sets of permutations with the same cycle type, *unless* that cycle type consists of odd cycles of distinct lengths, in which case there are two conjugacy classes of permutations with that cycle type.

I hope you can now see that the representative elements you found for each of the conjugacy classes each have a different cycle type and that the permutations in each conjugacy class in $S_n$ are exactly those permutations with the same cycle type as each representative element.

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to throw this out there. I hope it helps. I am new here so I don't know how to type things to make them look nice like in LaTex. I know that there is a theorem that states that all $A_n$, where $n$ is greater than or equal to $5$ are simple. A group is simple if it's only normal subgroups are the identity subgroup or itself. So, $A_5$ is simple. Meaning that it is a normal subgroup of $S_5$.

Comment: That $A_5$ is a normal subgroup of $S_5$ has pretty much nothing to do with $A_5$ being simple. After all, $A_4$ is not simple, but it's a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: Oh Okay, Thank you for that. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @HowardRoark - I TeXified your post. You can click edit to see the changes I made.