# Conjugacy classes of a set of subgroups of $S_5$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be the symmetric group $S_5$ of permutations of five symbols. Consider the set $S$ of subgroups of $G$ that are isomorphic to the non-cyclic group of order $4$. Let us call two subgroups $H$ and $K$ belonging to $S$
as equivalent if they are conjugate (that is, there exists $g \in G$ such that $gHg^{-1}=K$). How many equivalence classes are there in $S$?

What I know: I know that a non-cyclic group of order $4$ in $S_5$ is $K=\{e, (1\ 2), (3\ 4), (1\ 2)(3\ 4)\}$. Now all the subgroups of order $4$ which are not generated by $4$-cycles are isomorphic to $K$. How to think further?

Comment: See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5). Conjugacy classses are just cycle types, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152355/is-there-a-fast-way-to-determine-the-conjugacy-classes-of-s-5).

Answer (score 1):

The klein four group $V_4\cong\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ is generated by commuting pairs of involutions.

Involutions, i.e. elements of order two, in $S_5$ have cycle type either $(ab)$ or $(ab)(cd)$, i.e. a $2$-cycle or a $2$-involution (product of two disjoint $2$-cycles). Exercise:

- Two $1$-cycles commute iff they are equal or disjoint.
- Two $2$-involutions commute iff they have the same support / fixed point.
- A $1$-cycle and $2$-involution commute iff the former is part of the latter.

Use this to show a klein four subgroup of $S_5$ must be conjugate to one of

$$ \langle (12),(34)\rangle, \quad \langle (12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle. $$

Comment: There are total 20 such subgroups. 15 of them have two non-identity elements of type (ab) and one element of type (ab)(cd). And 5 subgroups have all 3 non-identity elements of type (ab)(cd). But We, know that equivalence classes have the same number of elements. Then how is it possible that one equivalence class has 15 elements and other has 5?

Comment: @SurajKulkarni The statement "equivalence classes have the same number of elements" is false in general. And false in particular in this context for conjugacy classes of subgroups. It's possible you're confusing this situation for the different situation of cosets (which are also a particular kind of equivalence class) having the same size.

Comment: ohh understood. Thank you for clarifying confusion.